# Request Payload is not parsing Backward slash in Jmeter - Performance Testing

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am currently trying to pass the following request payload {\ "Account number \ ": \ "123456789 \ " to print on JSON using JSR233 Pre-processor in Jmeter. But it is ignoring the Backward slash while passing it. Kindly provide a solution for this issue.

Note: I have provided space between backward slashes because Stackoverflow keeps ignoring it.

Comment: Please re-write your question or provide screenshot what you want, what is problem.

Comment: I have rewritten it. Please check if this is clear.

Comment: To prevent SO formatting from touching your text, either use single backticks \` around it, or use the code formatting (aka, separate row, indent with 4 spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to print a [String](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings) containing backslashes in Groovy you need to [escape](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters) a backslash with another backslash like:

```
'{\\ "Account number \\ ": \\ "123456789 \\ "'
```

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)